# Migrating from spring 3 to 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a code snippet

```html
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
  class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
  <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
   <beans:list>
    <beans:bean
     class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
   </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I want to migrate this to spring 4
According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-core-aadm

I know that if i have something like this:

```html
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
 <b:property name="decisionVoters" ref="voters"/>
</b:bean>
```

I have to do :

```html
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
 <b:constructor-arg ref="voters"/>
</b:bean>
```

But i don't know how to do it in my case.. please help

I would also appreciate if you could point out the signifacance of property name thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry pretty stupid of me. This seems to work perfect.

```xml
    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```